# Diff between two files shows empty lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Am trying to get the difference between two files even though the file looks same it shows the difference that it has empty lines in the beginning

How can I remove the empty lines before doing the difference

I know sed -i '/^$/d should work but it didn't worked for me is there any other way

Thanks

Comment: Remember, a seemingly "blank line" can actually contain many things, including blanks and/or tabs.  Use `diff -B file1 file2`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [diff man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html):

```
-B, --ignore-blank-lines
              ignore changes where lines are all blank
```

Comment: Thanks alex. It removed the lines but added. Empty Line starting with  (

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all blank lines (containing no non-whitespace characters), you can do the following:

```
perl -i -pe 's/^\s*\z//' yourfile.txt
```

Or, assuming GNU sed:

```
sed -i '/[^ \t]/!d' yourfile.txt
```

This is not quite equivalent because perl's `\s` considers more things as whitespace than just space and tab.